# NGram Query in SQL Optimise

Tags: sql, teradata, n-gram

I'm writing a SQL Query in Teradata TD16. I'm trying to match two concatenated strings by NGrams (ie trigrams - 3 character NGrams). There must be at least 1 trigram between the stings. Unfortunately the only way I can think of doing it is through a cross join and matching on the NGram function. Is there a less resource intensive way of doing this.

```
SEL
a.Row_id AS Mstr_Row_Id
,b.Row_id AS Chk_Row_Id
,EditDistance(a.Concant_Addr_Ln_Pc,b.Concant_Addr_Ln_Pc) AS Edit_Distance
,Char_Length(Trim( Both From a.Concant_Addr_Ln_Pc)) AS Char_Len_Test_Addr
,(1.00 * (Char_Len_Test_Addr - Edit_Distance) / NullIfZero(Char_Len_Test_Addr)) *100.00 AS Prcnt

FROM ( SEL * FROM  VT_Addr_Master WHERE grp=1 AND Coalesce(Reliable_Score_1,0)< 100 ) AS a
CROSS JOIN VT_Addr_Check AS b
ON  Ngram(a.N_Gram_Smpl,b.N_Gram_Smpl,3)>0

QUALIFY Row_Number() Over(
PARTITION BY a.Row_id
ORDER BY Prcnt DESC)=1
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: No matter how you write it, it will always be based on a *non-equi-join* and thus result in a *product join* in Explain. The only way to reduce the number of comparisons is to add a condition like *first n characters of both strings must be equal*

Comment: Thanks dnoeth. Its an honour to have you reply. What if I approached this in a different way? What if I initially created tables to hold the ngrams (say first two Ngrams) in an index and then inner joined the index? It would eliminate unnecessary records and reduce the work of the product join. The question is, does TD have NGRAM creating function? Can it be hand coded? Do you have such SQL?

Comment: *the first two ngrams* will be `substr(x, 1,3)` and `substr(x, 2,3)` for trigrams, quite similar to *first 3 (or 4) characters*. If you try this approach you might need to add stats on those substrings (you can get the exact Collect Stats statement from Diagnostic Helpstats)